# Node.js console hangs after firebase database ref

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have looked at similar questions and none of the solutions are working for me. My code is very simple (pic 1), the console just hangs. I can put in a process.exit() at the end and it stops the execution, but this won't work because I need to do the ref in a for loop (pic 3) so the process.exit() won't work there or it just immediately stops the execution. I have tried goOffline(), app().delete(), so many things in so many places and it just will not work. It either executes the code and hangs, or executes nothing and stops.

Simple code that hangs:

```
firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var db = firebase.database().ref('\deals');
```

Code with process.exit() that stops the program but doesn't execute the db code:

```
firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var db = firebase.database().ref('\deals');
process.exit();
```

Ideally my goal:

```
firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var db = firebase.database()
for (var i=1; i < 5; i++){
    db.ref('\deals').on(do some stuff... )
}
// somehow need to exit when the loop completes, but it hangs
```

The big picture:
I have a simple text file that I am reading lines from, manipulating some data and storing it in an array. So I need to loop that array, and for each element check the database to see if it matches (is a duplicate), and if so, ignore it. If it's not a duplicate, then add it to the database. So a grander picture of my code would be:

```
firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);

const fs = require('fs'); 
fs.readFile('info1.txt', (err, data) => { 
    if (err) throw err; 
  
    var deal = data.toString().split("~");
    var i;
    for (i=0; i < deal.length; i++){
        var dealData = deal[i].split("\r\n");
        var newDealData = dealData.filter(function (el) {
            return el != '';
        });

        var category=newDealData[0];
        var asin=newDealData[1];

        firebaseApp.database().ref('\deals').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                var compareAsin= child.val().asin;
                var compareCategory= child.val().category;
              if (compareAsin == asin && compareCategory == category){
                  isMatch=1;
              }
            })

            if (isMatch){
                console.log("uh oh duplicate");
            } else {
                writeDealData(asin, category);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: While you are editing, you might also want to specify what you are using the reference for. Does the loop need to happen in sequence or can everything happen all at once? Are you looking to immediately end the program once the loop has finished?

Comment: I understand. I'll edit with more details and clarity of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you want to read data once, use `once()` instead of `on()`.  It returns a promise you can work with normally.

Comment: I changed it to once, it still hangs unfortunately but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep your database query snappy and light on resources used, I'd recommend storing a combined index field in your data: `{ "category-asin": "<category>-<asin>" }`.

This allows you to query your database for an individual entry without downloading the entire database, as in your current code. It also allows you to [index on it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#section-indexing-order-by-child) in your security rules.

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// for the given category and asin, return entries that contain that exact category and asin value.
function lookupDeal(category, asin) {
  return firebase.database().ref('deals').orderByChild('category-asin').equalTo(`${category}-${asin}`).once('value');
}

const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('info1.txt', (err, data) => { 
    if (err) {
        console.error('File Error:', err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
  
    const deals = data.toString().split("~");
    
    Promise.all(deals.map((deal) => {
        const dealData = deal.split("\r\n"); // <-- might want to use /(\r?\n)+/ instead to support both \r\n and \n line endings, while also skipping empty lines
        const newDealData.filter((e) => e != '');

        const [category, asin] = newDealData;
        
        return lookupDeal(category, asin)
            .then((snapshot) => {
                if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                    console.log(`duplicate found for category="${category}" and asin="${asin}", skipping.`);
                    return;
                }
                
                return writeDealData(asin, category); // make sure this returns a promise!
            });
    }))
    .then((writeResults) => {
        console.log('All sync operations completed successfully. Exiting.');
        process.exit();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Database error:', error);
        process.exit(1);
    })
});
```

**Note:** This answer can be further improved by changing out `fs.readFile` to it's promise form.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to type this out. The concepts are all starting to make sense now, I have learned a lot tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my gosh I did it! I want to scream I feel so smart!
I reorganized my code structure so that the database ref was not being looped over, but rather had the for loop inside of it.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("/deals");
ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    fs.readFile('info1.txt', (err, data) => { 
        if (err) throw err;  
        var deal = data.toString().split("~");
        var i;
        for (i=0; i < deal.length; i++){
            var dealData = deal[i].split("\r\n");
            var newDealData = dealData.filter(function (el) {
                return el != '';
            });
            var category='';
            var asin='';
            var isMatch=0;
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                var compareAsin= child.val().asin;
                var comparePromo= child.val().promoCode;
              if (compareAsin == asin && comparePromo == promoCode){
                  isMatch=1;
              }
            })

            if (isMatch){
                console.log(`duplicate row ${i} asin ${asin}, not added`);
            } else {
                writeDealData(asin, cateogry);
            }
        }
        process.exit();
    })
});
```

Comment: BTW: This code will break if `fs.readFile` throws an error as it won't be caught & handled anywhere. You have also spelt "cateogry" wrong on the "writeDealData" line.

Comment: Ah, I would have seen that had I actually LOOKED at the results, I just saw the program run without hanging and got ahead of myself. I will be going with your structure above.